# Is login hint available under the new Google Identity Services library?

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

- I'm making an app that connects to a google calender.
- I would like make the "sign-up with google" and "authorize to access
  calender" flow as seamless as possible.
- My understanding is that this can be done with "login hints":

From the docs at https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/how-user-authz-works

Adding a hint during authorization initialization--typically the email address of the user's Google Account--enables Google to skip the display of an account chooser, saving users a step. The ID Token credential returned by Sign In With Google contains the user's email address.

From past issues and digging around in the source, it looks I can run the "sign in with google" flow, and then pass an email from that to the authorisation flow like so:

[image]

This does redirect to a link with "login_hint=EMAIL_FROM_LOGIN_FLOW", but still displays the account selection.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this feature not yet supported in the new library?